# django error: ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application

Tags: python, django, wsgi, django-middleware

My application was working last night, not sure why it won't work this morning. I think that all I did was to create an app called `django` to store my models, tests, and views.

Getting this error, running django with the Heroku Postgres application on OS X and dj_database as middleware:

```
  File "/Users/{ME}/Projects/{PROJECT}/{PROJECT}/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 58, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    "could not import module '%s': %s" % (app_path, module_name, e)) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application
'{PROJECT}.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; could not import module
'{PROJECT}.wsgi': No module named core.wsgi
```

Relevant part of my `wsgi.py` file:

```py
"""
WSGI config for {PROJECT} project.

This module contains the WSGI application used by Django's development
server and any production WSGI deployments. It should expose a
module-level variable named ``application``. Django's ``runserver``
and ``runfcgi`` commands discover this application via the
``WSGI_APPLICATION`` setting.

Usually you will have the standard Django WSGI application here, but
it also might make sense to replace the whole Django WSGI application
with a custom one that later delegates to the Django one. For example,
you could introduce WSGI middleware here, or combine a Django
application with an application of another framework.

"""
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "do.settings")

# This application object is used by any WSGI server configured to use this
# file. This includes Django's development server, if the WSGI_APPLICATION
# setting points here.
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

# Apply WSGI middleware here.
# from helloworld.wsgi import HelloWorldApplication
# application = HelloWorldApplication(application)
```

Relevant (I think) part of my `settings.py` file:

```py
WSGI_APPLICATION = '{PROJECT}.wsgi.application'

# ...

import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(default='sqlite://db/sqlite3.db')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creating an app called `django` means that any `from django import X` is going to be looking at your app, not at the `django` framework.

In this case, the software is trying to import [`django.core.wsgi`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/wsgi.py), but it's now looking for this file in your app's code, where it's nowhere to be found; hence the error: `No module named core.wsgi`

---

**Give your app another name.**

You'll have to rename the folder that contains your app, and the `INSTALLED_APPS` entry in `settings.py`.

Comment: @fox Happy to help! Remember to make sure never to override another Python's module with yours : )

Comment: Yes, makes sense. One additional question -- the app was never listed under `INSTALLED_APPS`. I forget, do I have to list it there for django to pick it up if the app's directory is within my current project directory (i.e. `project\app`)?

Comment: @fox Yes, or `django` will not register the application and, among other things, not create the required DB tables.

Comment: okay, last q: how do I set up a relative path in the `INSTALLED_APPS` section?

Answer (score 0):

from the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/):

> You’ll need to avoid naming projects after built-in Python or Django components. In particular, this means you should avoid using names like **django** (which will conflict with Django itself) or **test** (which conflicts with a built-in Python package).